# Verifying password regular exp Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

On frontend side i have some password validation does user eneter good password here is what I use to check password

```
function passwordStrengthCheck(password1, password2, passwordsInfo) {
    //Must contain 5 characters or more
    var WeakPass = /(?=.{10,}).*/;
    //Must contain lower case letters and at least one digit.
    var MediumPass = /^(?=\S*?[a-z])(?=\S*?[0-9])\S{10,}$/;
    //Must contain at least one upper case letter, one lower case letter and one digit.
    var StrongPass = /^(?=\S*?[A-Z])(?=\S*?[a-z])(?=\S*?[0-9])\S{10,}$/;
    //Must contain at least one upper case letter, one lower case letter and one digit.
    var VryStrongPass = /^(?=\S*?[A-Z])(?=\S*?[a-z])(?=\S*?[0-9])(?=\S*?[^\w\*])\S{10,}$/;

    $(password1).on('keyup', function (e) {
        if (VryStrongPass.test(password1.val())) {
            passwordsInfo.removeClass().addClass('vrystrongpass').html("Please repeat password!");
            $('#password').addClass('passed');
            $('#passwordRepeat').attr('readonly', false);
        }
        else if (StrongPass.test(password1.val())) {
            passwordsInfo.removeClass().addClass('strongpass').html("Enter special chars to make even stronger");
            $('#passwordRepeat').attr('readonly', true);
        }
        else if (MediumPass.test(password1.val())) {
            passwordsInfo.removeClass().addClass('goodpass').html("Enter uppercase letter to make strong");
            $('#passwordRepeat').attr('readonly', true);
        }
        else if (WeakPass.test(password1.val())) {
            passwordsInfo.removeClass().addClass('stillweakpass').html("Enter digits to make good password");
            $('#passwordRepeat').attr('readonly', true);
        }
        else {
            passwordsInfo.removeClass().addClass('weakpass').html("Must be 10 or more characters");
            $('#passwordRepeat').attr('readonly', true);
        }
    });
```

The problem is what i need, when user enter all big letters like **QWEYUDDNNJDD@1**
It still says enter number, but number is there? But all letters are big caps, and that way rule does not recognize the digit i dont know way, and also i need validation to say that user has entered all big letters, i dont want to allow that, is there a simple rule to check if all letters are big, and also why when all big letteres digit is nor recognize?

Here is working fiddle, please enter all big letters and number you will see that somethign is wrong

http://jsfiddle.net/4G4g9/

Comment: please provide a fiddle with your code

Comment: To avoid strain/load on your servers it's maybe a good idea doing this but isn't verifying passwords client-side quite scary?!

Comment: I have server side regluar also, dont worry :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd simplify this by just using checks for lowercase letters, uppercase letters, and digits. (I'd probably also throw in a check for something other than any of those, for a "very" strong password.)

```
var lcletter = /[a-z]/;
var ucletter = /[A-Z]/;
var digit = /\d/;
var other = /[^\dA-Za-z]/;

if (lcletter.test(thePassword) && ucletter.test(thePassword) && digit.test(thePassword) && other.test(thePassord)) {
    // Very strong
}
else if (lcletter.test(thePassword) && ucletter.test(thePassword) && digit.test(thePassword)) {
    // Fairly strong
}
else if ...
```

By doing the tests separately, you don't run into issues with the order in which characters are found in the string vs. the order in which you've listed them in your expression.

I'd also throw a length requirement in there, simply by looking at `thePassword.length`.